# Find out all solutions of the congruence $x^2 \equiv29 \mod 5$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find out all solutions of the congruence $x^2 \equiv29 \mod 5$.

[Hint:Find the solutions of this congruence $\mod 5$ , $\mod 7$ , and $\mod 7$ , and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.]

Comment: No @kyla, you *first* tell us what we ask you, then you may show some self work you've done, and **then**, finally, we may discuss the question.

Comment: @kyla: $29\equiv 4 \pmod5$ if that helps.

Comment: Ok, let start from x^2 = 29mod5, 29mod5 = 4 = x^2, x=2 and x=-2. So I don't know what it's relate to the hint stated below the question.

Comment: Does it make any sense or non at all?

Comment: kyla, if you are confused about the hint, you should be --- it makes no sense whatsoever. Please make sure you have posted the question correctly and, if you have, ask your teacher whether there hasn't been some mistake.

Comment: Yes I will ask her. I believe you, there's something wrong with that kind of question. I'll ask her tomorrow and if she'll give a correction then maybe I can solve it by myself. If not then I'll come back ask for a help here with you.

Comment: From the hint, it is probably a misprint for $\rm\: x^2\equiv 29\,\ (mod\ 35).$

Answer (score 7):

From, the hint, the problem is probably a misprint for $\rm\:x^2\equiv 29\ \ (mod\ 35).\ $  By $\,5,7\,$ prime,

$\rm\quad x^2\equiv 4\ \ (mod\ 5)\:\Rightarrow\: 5\mid(x-2)(x+2)\:\Rightarrow\:5\mid x\!-\!2\ \ or\ \ 5\mid x\!+\!2\:\Rightarrow\:x\equiv \color{#0A0}2,\color{blue}{-2}\ \ (mod\ 5)$

$\rm\quad x^2\equiv 1\ \ (mod\ 7)\:\Rightarrow\: 7\mid(x-1)(x+1)\:\Rightarrow\:7\mid x\!-\!1\ \ or\ \ 7\mid x\!+\!1\:\Rightarrow\:x\equiv \color{#C00}1,-1\ \ (mod\ 7)$

Now combine solutions by CRT. If $\rm\:x\equiv a\pmod 5,\ \ x\equiv b\pmod 7\:$ then $\rm\: x = b + 7n,\:$ so $\rm\: mod\ 5\!:\ a \equiv x\equiv  b + 7n\equiv b+2n\!\iff\! \color{#90f}{2n\equiv a-b}.$

Case $\rm1\!:\,\ a\equiv \color{#0A0}2,\ b\equiv \color{#C00}1,\,\ $ hence $\rm\,\ mod\ 5\!:\ \color{#90f}{2n\equiv a-b} \equiv 1\equiv 6\:\Rightarrow\:n\equiv 3,\ $ so $\rm\ n = 3+5k,\ $ so $\rm\ x = b+7n = 1+7(3+5k) = 22+35k.\:$

Case $\rm2\!:\,\ a\equiv \color{#0A0}2,\ b\equiv -1,\, $ hence $\rm\, mod\ 5\!:\ \color{#90f}{2n\equiv a-b} \equiv 3\equiv 8\:\Rightarrow\:n\equiv 4,\ $ so $\rm\ n = 4+5k,\ $ so $\rm\ x = b+7n = -1+7(4+5k) = 27+35k.\:$

The other $\,2\,$ cases $\rm\: (a,b)\equiv (\color{blue}{-2},\color{#C00}1),\ (\color{blue}{-2},-1)\:$ are solved similarly.

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20CRT%20combination%20root) for further details and many more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could start like this:
$x^2 \equiv 29 \pmod 5$ $\Leftrightarrow$
$x^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ $\Leftrightarrow$
$x^2-4 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ $\Leftrightarrow$
$(x-2)(x+2) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ $\Leftrightarrow$
$5\mid (x-2)(x+2)$

Comment: BTW I don't really see how this is related to Chinese remainder theorem. Are you sure you copied the assignment correctly?

Comment: Yes, what do you think of that kind of question? Is there's something wrong? If it is, who is to blame? The teacher or me....hahaha