# How to find the solutions of a^2 = [29] mod 35?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, congruences

How to find the solutions of: $$a^2 = [29]_{35}$$ ?

**(Brutal) Attempt:**
Since $Z_{35}$ contains only 35 elements, one could just brute force the calculation of $a^2$ for every element a $\in Z_{35}$ that GCD(a,35). When you find a number that verifies the equation, automatically you find another solution which is the inverse of that solution $\in Z_{35}$.

Do you know any **non brutal** way?

*NOTE: it doesn't have to require the quadratic congruence solving (I have only studied linear congruences)*

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem, see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340484/find-out-all-solutions-of-the-congruence-x2-equiv29-mod-5 (see the top answer - it is mod 35 in that example). In fact this is the same problem.

Comment: *Since 35 contains only 35 elements* - Actually, since we're dealing with squares, their number can be cut in half, since $n$ and $35-n\equiv-n\mod35$ have the same value when squared, namely $n^2$...

Comment: Also $29\equiv64\pmod{35}, 64=8^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $35 = 7 \times 5$, so solving the congruence relation is the same as solving the follwoing system:

$$a^2 \equiv 29 \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \iff (a-2)(a+2) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$
$$a^2 \equiv 29 \equiv 1 \pmod 7 \iff (a-1)(a+1) \equiv 0 \pmod 7$$

Because we have prime modulii then exactly one of the number is divisible by $5,7$. Check every possible combination (there are 4 combinations in this case) and then just simply apply Chinese Remainder Theorem.

---

**UPDATE:** Here's an example for finding one solution. As I've said exactly one of the factors is divisible by one. One combination is:

$$a - 2 \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \iff a \equiv 2 \pmod 5$$
$$a - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 7 \iff a \equiv 1 \pmod 7$$

Now just apply the Chinese Remadiner Theorem to "glue" the two relations (I assume you know how to do that) and you'll get that $a \equiv 22 \pmod {35}$ is one solution. Now you have three more combinations to go.

If you don't understand how to get $(a-2)(a+2) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ from $a^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$, then it's easier just to take square root and you'll get $a \equiv \pm 2 \pmod 5$. We can certainly do this because $4$ is a square and $5$ is a prime number. Actually this works due to the factorization I've posted earlier.

Comment: If a student had handed this in as part of an exercise, I'd have pulled out the red marker and complained that $(a-2)(a+2) (\operatorname{mod} 5)$ is not a (mathematical) statement.

Comment: How do you go from $a^2 \equiv 29 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ to $(a-2)(a+2) \pmod 5$

Comment: @roman My bad I forget the equivalency sign

Comment: @Deleted I think $29 \equiv 4 \mod 5$ is clear. Then just subtract 4 from both sides and then use the formula for difference of squares.

Comment: Now it's clear. It's still unclear the last part. Could you please make it less abstract?

Comment: @Deleted I've posted more detailed explanation now. I hope it's starting to get clearer for you.